# Backup Windows server Azure VM new Azure Recovery Service Vault error code BMSUserErrorContainerObjectNotFound

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I have a new vm, Operating system Windows (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter).
When I try to enable backup and select new Recovery Service Vault, I get deployment error:

Deployment to resource group test failed.
Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.

**Resource**
vault242/Azure/iaasvmcontainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;test;web01/vm;iaasvmcontainerv2;test;web01

**Type**
Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems

**Status**
Conflict

**Status message**
{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
"code": "BMSUserErrorContainerObjectNotFound",
"message": "Item not found"
}
}

Can't find any information for code BMSUserErrorContainerObjectNotFound and why a protected item not created automatically

Comment: getting the same error out of nowhere with a freshly bootstrapped vm

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for the delay in the response.
Were you able to resolve the issue?

If not, let's review it.
As I understood, you are enabling the Azure VM Back Up by following the [next steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm#back-up-from-azure-vm-settings):
[image]

There could be multiple reasons why you are getting this failure.

Did you perform these steps manually using the Azure Portal? [Template deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-rm-template-samples)? Scripting? I suspect most likely you are doing the template deployment or any kind of scripting and this one is the syntax issue.

Second thought, it was the transmitted issue due to the load of request on the Azure end. In this case, you need to retry the operation.

Additional question to ask, do you get the failure on one specific machine or all machines? Specific region?

Do you get the same failure when you use the existing vault?

If you still can provide information above, it's going to be helpful to narrow down the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error as well today and I think it is is a Azure portal bug when enabling the Backup from the VM blade.

Instead, you can initiate a Backup from the "Recovery Services vaults" blade and add the VM to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue with a Policy deployment of backup.

Another VM with the same name had been backed up previously, and after purging that backup we were able to re-apply policy with a Remediation task and succeed.